# Illegal repetition exception when using String.replaceAll() method

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code:

```
    public String replaceValues(String string, HashMap hashMap){
    TestHashMap h = new TestHashMap();
    String str = new String(h.xmlToString());
    Iterator iterator = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        HashMap.Entry pair = (HashMap.Entry)iterator.next();
        str = str.replaceAll(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue().toString());
    }
    return str; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestHashMap h = new TestHashMap();
    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmap.put("{username}", "Tudor");
    hmap.put("{password}", "Tester123");
    System.out.println(hmap);
    String replace = h.replaceValues(h.xmlToString(), hmap);
    System.out.println(replace);
}
```

XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hashmap>
    <request>
        <username>{username}</username>
        <password>{password}</password>
    </request>
</hashmap>
```

This throws exception: Illegal repetition. But there is no way that i know of to escape the "{}" characters, because the way i'm getting those is with getKey() and getValue() methods, which returns me {password} and {username} as expected. However it breaks at `String replace = h.replaceValues(h.xmlToString(), hmap)` line. Any solutions please? It's worth mentioning that if i replace {password} with a random value (for example "password1") the code above works without issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `replaceAll` method uses regular expressions, with `{` and `}` having special meaning. If you use `replace(String, String)` instead they're treated as normal Strings and there is no such issue.

Comment: And despite the confusing name `replaceAll()` implying "not all" behaviour for `replace()`, `replace()` does in fact replace all occurrences.

Comment: maybe you could add a reference to `Pattern.quote(String)`, but using `replace(String, String)` is probably the better solution since there is apparently no need for regular expressions, actually could be error prone to use it

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!